# How this @OneToMany relationship should look like when using Map?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have `Order` and `Dish` Entities. Order contains a map of Dish-Integer ( dish and how many times it was ordered ).

But I can't figure out what to write above map when I have a key as an Entity. How join column should look like.

```
    @Entity

        public class Order {
        @OneToMany(
                mappedBy = "order",
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true)
            private Map<Dish, Integer> dishesQuantity = new HashMap<>();
    }
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public class Dish {
        private Order order;
}
```

P.S. I would also appreciate it if you could tell me what happens if I skip annotating the join column.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public class Order {
    @OneToMany(
                mappedBy = "order",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true)
    private Map<Dish, Integer> dishesQuantity = new HashMap<>();
    }



    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name ="dishes_quantity")
    public class Dish {
        private Order order;
    }
```

As I know to use `@JoinColumn`is mapping foreign key. To use @JoinColumn annotation you can set foriegnkey name. If you don't use it. It will be automapping with `Entity_ID` of opposite entity field.
But I usually set @JoinColumn(name ='') to mapping field clearly.